# Not able to get DataMemberBinding in the telerik Datagridview

Tags: telerik, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

Hello I am using Telerik Rad Controls for the DataGrid view...

I want to display only some required columns in the DataGrid.. so I used this code

```
 <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
     <telerik:GridViewColumn  Header="Market Code"  />
     <telerik:GridViewColumn Header="Market Name" />
  </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
```

But I was not able to set the binding.. I was not able to set the DataMemberBinding to the column...

It says the property was not found in the GridViewColumn....

```
 <riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="True" 
                               Height="0" 
                               LoadedData="mKT_MSTRDomainDataSource_LoadedData_1" 
                               x:Name="mKT_MSTRDomainDataSource"
                               QueryName="GetMKT_MSTRQuery" Width="0" >

        <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <my:GNDataDomainContext />
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>

    </riaControls:DomainDataSource>
    <telerik:RadGridView Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Data,
                         ElementName=mKT_MSTRDomainDataSource}"
                         x:Name="mKT_MSTRRadGridView" Width="Auto" 
                         Canvas.Left="290" Height="300" >
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewColumn  Header="Market Code" DataMemberBinding=""  />
            <telerik:GridViewColumn Header="Market Name" />
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Can anyone help me where am I making mistake... please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to choose an appropriate type of column for binding, e.g. GridViewDataColumn, etc. depending on your data type. You can see the list of pre-defined column types [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/gridview-columns-overview.html).
 You then need to bind the columns to the data you want to display, with the DataMemberBinding attribute:

```
<telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  Header="Market Code" DataMemberBinding="{Binding MarketCode}"  />
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Market Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding MarketName}"/>
</telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
```

where MarketCode and MarketName are properties on your data records